# Optimization problems linked together by time

Tags: math, optimization

Let's say i'm trying to minimize a function f1(x) with x a vector. This is a classic optimization problem and I get a solution, let's say the vector x_opt = (0, 700, 0, 1412, 0, 5466).

Now i have another function to minimize f2(x), and I know this function is related to the same individual and should have x_opt close to the first one. So, if i have (700, 0,  0, 1454, 0, 5700) I won't be happy with the solution, but if the first one was (700, 0, ...) or if the second one is (0, 700, ...) I'd be happy.

Is it ok to minimize f1(x1) + f2(x2) + lambda * || x2-x1 ||

What norm should I use, should i set lambda to one ?
What if i have more than two functions and I know f1 and f2 are more closely related than f3 and f2 and f3 and f1 ?

Is there any literature on this topic, or a name ? Because I don't even know where to look

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this question is off-topic on StackOverflow. The `math` tag "involves the manipulation of numbers *within a program*". Please ask it on MathOverflow.

Comment: This is linked to *regularization*, *multi-objective optimization* and probably *local neighborhoods*. `What norm should I use, should i set lambda to one ?` Depends on your idea of a neighborhood. Are outliers bad, go for l2-norm, if not, maybe l1-norm.  `What if i have more than two functions and I know f1 and f2 are more closely related than f3 and f2 and f3 and f1 ?` You can extend your idea -> multiple lambdas. This is a *convex combination* then (if you design then to sum up to 1).

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know stackoverflow was meant to be only for programming stuff. My bad.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sascha